# Demoting 2008 domain controllers in a multi-DC environment

Tags: domain-controller

This seems like a silly question, but I've looked everywhere and cannot find the answer in any videos.

I am assuming that demoting a DC in AD in a multi DC environment is exactly the same process as demoting a DC in a single DC environment, except that in a single scenario, you are deleting Active Directory entirely.  Is that correct?

I'm 99% sure that demoting a single DC will not delete or alter Active directory on the other DCs, but I have no one to ask and I'm afraid I will make a huge mistake if I do not 100% know what I am doing.

The scenario I have is that we have 3 2016 DCs and 3 2008 DCs in a 2008 functional level domain.  I need to ditch the 2008 machines to raise the functional level.  What is the process to demote the 2008 DCs?

Answer (score 1):

You can demote the 2008 without problem if, and only if you have the global catalogue on atleast one other alive DC.

Be sure the DFR/FRS replication work good too. (aka for SYSVOL, NETLOGON)

A bad replication would not kill your domain, but can give headache and block user login for the time you fix the replication, but a missing global catalogue might bring down your domain.